# Log in not working using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written scrapy code for log in to a site. first i tried for one site. It worked well. But then i changed the url and tried for other site. It is not working for that site. I used the same code without any change. What would be the problem?

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quote'
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        token=response.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()

        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'csrf_token':token,'password':'foo','username':'foo'},callback=self.scape_home_page)

    def scape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

This worked well.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class BucketsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'buckets'
    allowed_domains = ['http://collegekart.in/login']
    start_urls = ['http://collegekart.in/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        token=response.xpath('//meta[@name="csrf-token"]/@content').extract_first()
        print(token)
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'csrf-token':token,'password':'*********','username':'**************'},callback=self.scape_home_page)

    def scape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print("yes")
```

This is not working. Please help to solve this.

Comment: If one script works for one site, it doesn't mean that it will work for another site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong

- `........from_response(**response**........

  - if you check the `response.url`, it will give you `http://collegekart.in/login/` instead of `http://collegekart.in/`
- `allowed_domains =`**`['http://collegekart.in/login']`**

  - the login GET Request of `collegekart.in/` is not in your `allowed_domains`

### How to fix it

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class BucketsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'buckets'
    allowed_domains = ['collegekart.in']
    start_urls = ['http://collegekart.in/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        token=response.xpath('//meta[@name="csrf-token"]/@content').extract_first()
        print(token)
        response = response.replace(url='http://collegekart.in/')
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'csrf-token':token, 'password':'hanfenghanfeng','username':'zerqqr1@iydhp.com'},callback=self.scape_home_page)

    def scape_home_page(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print("yes")
```

### Why?

- If you didn't replace the `url` variable in `response`:

  - scrapy will send your request to an incorrect url:
    `http://collegekart.in/`**`login/`**`access/attempt_login?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=zerqqr1%40iydhp.com&password=hanfenghanfeng`
  - This is the correct url: `http://collegekart.in/access/attempt_login?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=zerqqr1%40iydhp.com&password=hanfenghanfeng`
- Login GET url is not included in `allowed_domains`

  - `allowed_domains = ['http://collegekart.in/login']`
  - Login GET url: `http://collegekart.in/access/.......`

## Suggestions

- Use `Chrome's Inspector > Network` to see the actual request being made when performing Login actions
- Check this scrapy official tutorial (PDF Version): [Link](https://d.pr/free/f/gYG73Y)

Comment: THANQ so much! It worked. I am a newbie. I am learning now. Thank you again

Comment: @user8931234, If it solves your problem, make sure to accept it as an answer by ticking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here change the response url accordingly, this wil  solve the problem.